# Is there a jsonp interface on the web that will give me the destination of a redirect link?

Tags: javascript, json, redirect, jsonp

See title for question.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please define *destination of a redirect link*.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know of any because this is a rather trivial use case.
relying on something external and accepting the risk of your application to get disfunctional or compromised for this trivial feature is in my opinion rather stupid.

if you mean bei destination of a redirect link the value of the location header at a girven resource, you can just issue a head request and parse this header.

i don't see whats this got to do with jsonp. how you pass the results to your application is up to you. you can also do it client side.